# Unable to get instance of Activity in Unity C#

Tags: java, c#, android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to access an Activity method from Unity and cannot figure out for the life of me why it is not working. I've read various pages such as http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/call-a-method-in-an-activity-using-androidjavaobject.219950/ and http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

I'm trying to create a Camera plugin for Unity. There are some plugins out there, but most are outdated and don't work. I could use the knowledge anyway for future use. I was originally just using a regular Java class, but to take a picture, I discovered that the best route was to use an Intent due to the fact that it's being used for quick photos, not a personalized camera application. To use an Intent, an Activity must be used. The Activity is passed to the Intent, but the Activity also has to override a method to receive the result from the Intent as outlined in Android documentation. I would link to it but I'm limited to 2 links.

I'm using this to access the activity. The AndroidJavaClass initializes successfully, however, when I try and get the context, I get a null ptr error in logcat.

## C# code

```
    AndroidJavaClass link = new AndroidJavaClass("com.syncedsoftware.cameralink.CameraLinkActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = link.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLinkContext"); // jni null ptr!

    activity.Call("TakePicture");
```

It never reaches activity.Call("TakePicture");.

## Java class -UPDATED WITH STATICS-

```
public class CameraLinkActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

private static Context cameraLinkContext;

public static Context getLinkContext(){
    Log.v("Unityx", "GetLinkContext()");
    return cameraLinkContext;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("Unity", "OnCreate");
    cameraLinkContext = this;
}

public void TakePicture(){
    Log.v("Unity", "TakePicture()");
}
}
```

## Logcat output -UPDATED WITH NEW STATIC IMPLEMENTATION-

```
05-29 12:32:50.560    3408-3498/? V/Unityx﹕ GetLinkContext()
05-29 12:32:50.810    3408-3498/? I/Unity﹕ Exception: JNI: Init'd AndroidJavaObject with null ptr!
        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject..ctor (IntPtr jobject) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.AndroidJavaObjectDeleteLocalRef (IntPtr jobject) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.CallStatic[AndroidJavaObject] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        at AndroidCameraLink.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

<strike>Something I noticed is that the message in onCreate() is never displayed. This leads me to believe that the Activity is not being properly created or created at all.</strike> The Activity is never being "created", thus onCreate() is never called to initialize the Context field.

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.syncedsoftware.cameralink"     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
  <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
<activity android:name="com.syncedsoftware.cameralink.CameraLinkActivity" /> 
      </application>
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
      <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
</manifest>
```

If someone could explain why this is not working, I would be very grateful. I've been trying to figure this out for almost a week now, to no avail. This is my first time treading into native territory with Unity, please excuse my ignorance.

## UPDATE: getLinkContext() is being called, but the problem persists.

After flipping the implementation to static, I discovered that I was overlooking the logcat message. When flipping it to static, getLinkContext() is successfully called, however, this doesn't fix the original issue of not being able to get the instance of the Activity.

cameraLinkContext is null because onCreate() is never called. The Activity is never being "created".

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used any Activity that extends UnityPlayerNativeActivity (We switched to a completely different method of making plugins a long time ago), so I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that the issue might lie in the fact that your custom Activity (com.syncedsoftware.....) isn't marked as the MainActivity in the Manifest. Basically, swap out the "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" with your activity's name in the manifest.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios After doing this, the app won't even launch. I get a toast message that says "Application not installed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to forge a solution based on a YouTube tutorial(link below if interested).

## The Problem

The problem was residing in the fact that Unity did not *technically* know about the activity, despite it being defined in the manifest, therefore it was not able to create it. Someone pointed this out below, but when I made my activity the main activity, the app would refuse to launch. This was the correct approach, but there was more to it as described below.

## The Solution

In order to get it to work, I had to copy the original implementation of UnityPlayerActivity, and paste it into my Java project. There, I customized it accordingly, and extended UnityPlayerActivity. I set the activity as the main activity in the manifest. Instead of attempting to call on the activity method directly, I made a "bridge" class to do it for me. This simplified matters. UnityPlayer.currentActivity in the Java classes holds a reference to, well, the current activity that is being used in the UnityPlayer. Which is, in this case, my customized class. I was able to call the Intent using this, and it all works flawlessly now.

## Step By Step Fix

The first step was to copy the original implementation of UnityPlayerActivity.java(found in a Unity installation sub folder) and customize it. It also extends UnityPlayerActivity (the original) to make sure everything is properly linked into Unity. The original implementation defines a lot of objects and methods that make the Unity player work in the first place.

## UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
package com.syncedsoftware.player; // changed package name

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class UnityPlayerActivity extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity // extends the ORIGINAL implementation
{

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   // Process intent data
}

// Setup activity layout
@Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

The second step was to add the activity in as the main activity in the manifest.

## AndroifManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.syncedsoftware.inventory" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="false" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
<activity android:name="com.syncedsoftware.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

The third step was to add in a "bridge" class to call upon within Unity for easy access.

## LinkBridge.java

```
package com.syncedsoftware.cameralink;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

/**
 * Created by Anthony on 5/30/2015.
 */
public class LinkBridge {

public static void ShowCamera(int requestCode){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, requestCode); // Gets custom activity and uses the callback accordingly
}

}
```

Finally, we add code in Unity to trigger ShowCamera().
    #C# code
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.syncedsoftware.cameralink.LinkBridge");
    jc.CallStatic("ShowCamera", 1);

After days (literally) of searching for an answer, I came across this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4l64nUGt0l0 This helped a lot! I flipped the implementations around accordingly to suit my Camera intent situation.

Answer (score 1):

You get null pointer exception, since you try calling non-static method on AndroidJavaClass

Comment: If I change the implementation to static, it calls getLinkContext() successfully, but it still throws a jni null ptr. Which is probably because the activity is not initializing. The context is NULL because onCreate() is never called.

Comment: The post has been updated to reflect this. Your solution fixed one of the problems, thank you! The Activity, however, still is not being 'created'.